# Make the PHP MySql Search Engine and Pagination work

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I don't know how to make the search through another table. how should i do that?
the table name is comments and i want to search for all the post stored in the column name kom

Another thing is that i cant get the pagination start working...
I started the pagination within an else statment because i only need it when i get more than 1 result.
I can get the page links showing and limit the search posting showing but when i click on one off the links i cant get to the next page
Heres the code

```
<?php 
    $search = $_POST["search"];
    $field = $_POST["field"];

    if($_POST["submit"] && $search)
    {   
        echo "<div id='result'>";
        echo "<h2>Resultat</h2>";
    $search = strtoupper($search);
    $search = strip_tags($search);
    $search = trim($search);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' 
              UNION 
              SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE post LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $matches = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($matches == 0)
        //code if serch didnt result any results

    else if($matches == 1)
            //code if the matches only 1

    else
    {

        $per_page = 4;
        $pages = ceil($matches / $per_page);
        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page']: 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' 
                          UNION 
                          SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE post LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start, $per_page";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conn) or die(mysql_error());


        echo "<font size='-1'>Sökningen $search gav $matches resultat</font><br/>";
        while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $id = $r["id"]; 
            $title = $r["title"]; 
            $post = $r["post"]; 
            $time = $r["time"];

            echo "<br/><strong><a href='comment.php?id=$id'>$title</a></strong><br/>";
            echo "<font size='-1'>".substr($post, 0, 60)."</font><br/>";
            echo "<font size='-1'>".substr($post, 60, 70)."</font><br/>";
            echo "<font size='-3'>$time</font><br/>";   
        }

            //theese are showin but cannot click of any of them
                if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages)
            {
                for($nr = 1; $nr <= $pages; $nr++)
                {
                    if($nr == $page)
                        echo "<a href='?page=".$nr."' style='font-size:20px;'>$nr</a>";
                    else
                        echo "<a href='?page=".$nr."' style='font-size:15px;'>$nr</a> ";
                }
            } 
        }   
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you're struggling with? Is the script too slow?

Comment: the pagination and also would like to search through another table, right now it only search throug one table

Comment: "to optimize" has another meaning. Edited your question

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you are using a `UNION`?

If not, you can change:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' 
          UNION 
          SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE post LIKE '%$search%'";
```

to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogTable WHERE (title LIKE '%$search%') OR (post LIKE '%$search%')";
```

Anyway, I would never execute the same query twice, just get the first x results if no start parameter was given (for example a page number in the query string) and calculate the start point when a start parameter was given.

And if you want the total, use a `COUNT(*)` query or change your query:

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM blogTable WHERE (title LIKE '%$search%') OR (post LIKE '%$search%')";
```

Comment: No not really, but it also worked. Now i search through one table. How would i do to search through another table with the column name `comments`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that catches the eye is that the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Get rid of the `strip_tags()` (if it's for security, in which case it's useless) and do a `mysql_real_escape_string()` on every value you use in the search queries, or check whether the value is actually a number when using `int` columns.

Another thing is that the `<font>` tag is outmoded. The cool CSS way of styling text is having an external CSS stylesheet, and defining in it something like

```
span.small { font-size: 12px; color: green }
```

and then using it in the HTML like so:

```
<span class="small">Text goes here</span>
```

that said, this probably belongs on CodeReview.SE....

Comment: have changed the `strip_tags()` to `mysql_real_escape_string()` now, thanks for the information!

and for now i dont care about the css :P

Answer (score 0):

First, I always recommend to use GET method and not POST method for searches and filters, next, maybe this [pagination php](http://www.aprender-a-programar.com/paginacion-php) class can help you.